# How to forbid using Primitive Types

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a class `SomeClass<E extends SomeInterface>`, 
and I dont want client use `SomeClass` as a primitive type like this: `new SomeClass()`,
I only want client to use it as a generic type: `new SomeClass<SomeInterfaceImpl>()`,
beacause I have write some method inside `SomeClass` which is based on `SomeInterface`.
how can i do that?

Comment: If you say `new SomeClass()`, that is by definition *not* a primitive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is **not** a *primitive type*; that is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2970947). And you **can't** prevent their use. Prior to Java 5, there were no generic types. Through [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) they were added to the language (and incur no runtime overhead). However, one consequence of that decision (combined with maintaining backwards compatibility) is the raw type.